# Change upstream response from 302 to 301 in nginx

Tags: nginx, redirect

I have a Django app as an upstream using Gunicorn in nginx, and that app sometimes sent me back a 302 with a Location. And that it's perfectly fine.

We can't touch Django's code but colleagues need the 302 to be 301.

So I would like to modify that 302 to 301, but I haven't found a way to do it without using LUA.
I have tried combinations of "error_page" statement, eg. `error_page 302 =301 @redirect;` with the "proxy_intercept_errors on;", named location, etc. but haven't had any luck.

Is there any quick way to achieve it? Thanks.

Edit1: Here below my pretty simple upstream:

```
upstream test {
  server unix:/webapps/test/gunicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}
```

Comment: Please add your upstream conf sample txt

Comment: @YonzLeon added, thanks, it is pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the 3xx status code by using `proxy_intercept_errors` and `error_page` as you suggest.

You will need to use the value from `$upstream_http_location` to reconstruct the `Location` header in the replacement response.

In its simplest form, you could use:

```
proxy_intercept_errors on;
error_page 302 = @redirect;
location @redirect {
    return 301 $upstream_http_location;
}
```

In this case, `$upstream_http_location` is the original value for the `Location` header in the response from the upstream server before being transformed by `proxy_redirect` - equivalent to using `proxy_redirect off;`.

This may be sufficient for your needs.

---

However, if you need to rewrite the `Location` response header - for example, if you are using `proxy_redirect default;` - you may need to modify the response using a `map`.

For example:

```
map $upstream_http_location $location {
        ~^https?://[^/]+(.*)$    $1;
        default                  /oops;
}

server {
    ...
    proxy_intercept_errors on;
    error_page 302 = @redirect;
    location @redirect {
        return 301 $location;
    }
}
```

Comment: Richard, your simplest form works, but the login stopped working. I noticed that it didn't sent the headers, so I resolved doing
    location @redirect {
        add_header Set-Cookie "sessionid=${upstream_cookie_sessionid}; HttpOnly; Path=/; SameSite=Lax";
        add_header Set-Cookie "csrftoken=${upstream_cookie_csrftoken}; Path=/; SameSite=Lax";
        return 301 $upstream_http_location;
    }

is there any better way of passing headers? Right now I'm missing the "expires" part.